# Ruby code runs without instantiation or method calls

Tags: ruby, selenium

first post here. I'm a novice programmer as you'll see, and I'm learning to use Ruby to write automated functional tests. I generated the source below from Selenium IDE and I've been tinkering with it but I don't understand why this code runs without instantiation or method calls.

```
require 'rubygems'
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

DataDir='Users/CH/src/ruby/data'

class Case1 < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    #@driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_case1
    @root_url="http://www.google.com"
    @driver.get @root_url+"/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&biw=1440&bih=716&source=hp&q=Test&pbx=1&oq=Test&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3631l4283l0l4700l4l4l0l0l0l0l272l860l0.2.2l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=10e90fa4cbd35dc9"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").send_keys "test"
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
     yield
  rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
     @verification_errors << ex
  end
end
```

Sorry if it's a hopelessly n00b question but no amount of Googling has helped answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `test/unit` (actually `minitest/unit` if you're on Ruby 1.9.x) contains the code to execute the test cases that you define. You can browse around the source [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/lib/minitest/) and [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/lib/test/) if you like, to see how it's done. Essentially the `require 'test/unit'` line will ultimately call the `autorun` method on Test::Unit, which knows how to run your tests.

Comment: Thank you too. It's good to know that I didn't know the answer to this question through ignorance rather than an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Nutshell version is that classes can do things when they're extended, including turning methods starting with `test_` into test suite tests, running them, and aggregating their results.

The `Kernel.at_exit` method can also be used to create `Proc`s from blocks to be run when a program exists.

Combine the two, and voila.

Check out the source for in-depth details, more than may be easily-digestible at this point.